# How to access local files from google drive with python?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm working on **Google colaboratory** notebook on Google Drive. I want to write Python code to access my local disk to read some files.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try local runtimes:
http://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Or, see this example notebook for file sharing recipes:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb